# yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: while constructing a Python object cannot find "module_name" in the module '__main__'

Tags: python, configuration, yaml, config, pyyaml

I have tried construct some classes from file.yml

Stucture of priters.yml you can see bellow:

```
--- !Station
recipients:
        - &first_phone ['Max']
        - &second_phone ['Anna', 'Alisa']
obj:
        - &first !!python/object:__main__.Nokia
                model: Nokia_8800
                recipients: *first_phone
        - &second !!python/object:__main__.Apple
                model: iPhone4
                recipients: *second_phone
spam_station: !station
    Nokia: *first
    Apple: *second
```

The class constructor is presented in spam_station.py

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Union
from yaml import YAMLObject, load

class AbstrackPhone(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def send_message(self, message):
        pass

class Nokia(AbstrackPhone):
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = None
        self.recipients = []

    def send_message(self, message):
        for recipient in self.recipients:
            print(f"Hi {recipient} i'm {self.model}. {message}")


class Apple(AbstrackPhone):
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = None
        self.recipients = []

    def send_message(self, message):
        for recipient in self.recipients:
            print(f"Hi {recipient} i'm {self.model}. {message}")


class ConstructStation(YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = u'!Station'

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(Class, loader, node):
        def get_satation(loader, node):
            data = loader.construct_mapping(node)
            station = Class.Station()
            station.add_phones(data.values())
            return station

        loader.add_constructor(u"!station", get_satation)
        return loader.construct_mapping(node)['spam_station']

    class Station():

        def __init__(self):
            self.senders = []

        def add_phones(self, phones: Union[list, str]):
            self.senders.extend(phones)

        def send_message(self, message, **kwargs):
            for sender in self.senders:
                sender.send_message(message, **kwargs)

def station():
    with open('../yaml_config/printers') as file:
        spam_station = load(file)
    return spam_station

if __name__ == "__main__":
    station().send_message('Good luck!!!')
```

I've tried import and use 'station' in sender.py:

```
from station.spam_station import station

if __name__ == "__main__":
    station().send_message('Good luck!!!')
```

when i run spam_station.py, it's ok:

```
Hi Max i'm Nokia_8800. Good luck!!!
Hi Anna i'm iPhone4. Good luck!!!
Hi Alisa i'm iPhone4. Good luck!!!
```

when i run sender.py, i've error:

```
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: while constructing a Python object
cannot find 'Nokia' in the module '__main__'
  in "../yaml_config/printers", line 7, column 11
```

How to solve this problem? Please tell me, what is a good practice for configuring python objects to yaml. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you execute `sender.py`, that file (and not `spam_station.py`) is `__main__`.

Probably the best solution is to avoid depending on import paths in the YAML file. You already do that with `Station`, so you can simply do it on the other classes as well:

```py
class Nokia(AbstrackPhone, YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = u"!Nokia"
    def __init__(self, model = None, recipients = []):
        self.model = model
        self.recipients = recipients

    def send_message(self, message):
        for recipient in self.recipients:
            print(f"Hi {recipient} i'm {self.model}. {message}")
```

Now you can use `!Nokia` instead of `!!python/object:__main__.Nokia` in the YAML file. Same goes for the `Apple` class.